# Trying to send broadcast message to devices on network and getting a response back

Tags: python, sockets, networking, broadcast

I will try to explain my problem as best I can. I am basically trying to connect a device (smart sensor) linked via Ethernet to my computer onto my application. This device replies via UDP if specific messages in bytes are sent. I basically want to see the IP addresses of all the smart sensors on my network. In this instance, I want to send a broadcast message to any device I find on a network and the sensor will reply something if that message is received. At that moment, I will know that the only device(s) that replied on that network will be the sensor(s). So I can broadcast `01 00 00 00` in hex bytes onto the network and the sensor will reply `00 00 00 00` along with its IP address. This means I will know the IP adress of the sensor and the application can connect to that sensor.

I used Wireshark to see what happens when I run my code and I see that the message was successfully broadcasted and that the sensor replied.

[image: sent message]
: `192.168.11.2` is the ethernet connection IP address (I am connected to the Internet with another Ethernet cable so that IP address is not my PC's actual IP address)

[image: sent message contents]
And here, the last 4 bytes is the message im sending (`01 00 00 00`)

[image: sensor IP address]
Here's the IP address of the smart sensor that received the message I sent and replied.

[image: message reply contents]
Here's the message on Wireshark that received. The highlighted bytes are the IP address of the sensor and the last 4 bytes (`00 00 00 00`) are the actual message I should be receiving.

Here's the Python code I'm running.

```
#sending broadcast
s = socket.socket(family = socket.AF_INET, type = socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00', ('192.168.255.255', 8002))

#receiving message
sr = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sr.bind(('192.168.11.2', 8002))
print("successfully run bind")
sr.settimeout(10)
data, remote_addr=sr.recvfrom(1024) #gets stuck here (not receiving anything)
print("finished receiving")
print(remote_addr)
```

Now, like it says in the code, when I'm trying to receive, the app just hangs in the console until the timeout is set after 10 seconds. The port `8002` is the needed port for UDP to send messages to the smart sensor. I tried different ports when running `sr.bind()` but no success.

Comment: Why do you set up the receive socket only after you sent the message? The reply may well be missed when doing so.

Comment: So what I should do is initialize receiving socket `sr` before I send the message with the `s` socket? Like so?

`s = socket.socket(...)
sr = socket.socket(...)
sr.bind(...)
s.sendto(...)
`

Comment: Right, try that.

Comment: So if I bind before sending, I get this error: `OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`. If i change the port from 8002 to something else (I tried 4999), it still stays stuck until the timeout. Same thing if I bind after sending.

Comment: Now I'd use only one and the same socket for sending and receiving.

Comment: This is a misuse of broadcast. You want to use multicast. Broadcast interrupts every host on the LAN, including things like routers, printers, other uninterested hosts, etc., and it is a security risk.  Multicast only interrupts those hosts that have subscribed to the specific multicast group. Broadcast is basically deprecated, and it has been eliminated from IPv6, so you coul not port the application.

Comment: Also, UDP port 2 is assigned for a different service. You should not be using ports assigned to a different service.

Comment: The sensor replies to the sender of the broadcast (port 59599 in your sensor IP address image), so `s.recvfrom(1024)` should work.  You also would get the address of the sender using `recvfrom`, so the sensor sending the IP seems redundant, or use `s.recv(1024)` since the message has the IP.